# Meaning of "textbook Launch" in given sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, subcontinental-english

In a post-launch address from the Sriharikota launch port, K. Sivan, Chairman of the Indian Space Research Organisation(ISRO), hailed the event as a *textbook launch* of a very important and complex satellite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd imagine that in Indian English *textbook launch* means the same as it does in British or American English.

In this context, the textbook is being used as an adjective -

> [Textbook](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/textbook) - (of an example of something) extremely good, or thought to be usual or typical

So a *textbook launch* is a launch that proceeded exactly as it was planned to do, without any problems.